# How to correctly apply CSS styles to HTML element Clearance templates? (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: html, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, clearance

I'm using bootstrap 5 for fastest applying styles, but when I trying to apply styles for HTML element template, I have this:

Before applying

[image: Before applying]

After applying

[image: After applying]

Code (.html.erb):

```html
<div class="submit-field">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><%= form.submit %></button>
</div>
```

Under `<%= form.submit%>` hides as I understand a simple button template, but I can not find the source code of this template in any way, as if it works "out of thin air". Maybe there is a way how to find it or correctly apply CSS?

Comment: You can use browser developer tools (in this case HTML inspector). Find element and you will see css applied to this element and css source. Good to [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submit` form helper creates  button for you. You should apply class to the element like so:

```html
<div class="submit-field">
 <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary'%>
</div>
```

Your code created a button inside a button like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><button>Submit</button></button>
```